# Genre of song where instruments are replaced by vocals

Tags: identify-this-genre

I wanted to ask you what genre this song is: [Bring the noise - Prossimamente su Italia 1](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=oxpSP7QEAWY)

I am not talking about the original, I am talking about this remix where instruments are substituted by vocals, like Pentatonix does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *a capella* music (often rendered in recent times as *acapella*).  The original phrase is an Italian music term meaning "in the style of the chapel," but the English meaning is "music without instruments," meaning voices only, sometimes with the addition of body percussion.

*Acapella* is perhaps literally the oldest form of music, but there have been many different versions of it over the years, from the [monastic hymns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0yd5EE0hAB8) referred by the original Italian phrase to the [American barbershop quartets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkvjHE5MV2c) of the late 1800's and early 1900's.  There is a particularly strong acapella tradition in the black American community, starting with the [field hollers](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=prettiest+train) and [spirituals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7oFcFzJT7Tw&list=PLUCSU0WaWqtAb4XM1T5d5YZat0Mt3KMPI) of the slavery years, up through the aforementioned [barbershop quartets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZnwI6Ty2o0), the [doo-wop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSTdCJuJkIc&list=PLYeTwha8FiSzTkv-C_9ajXDxZSuqmvltN) of the 1950's, and the [acapella R&B hits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8b3mftcV0dY) of the early 90's.

A [newer style of acapella](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fG-1Nj3qro) focused around covers and adaptions of current pop music has been popular on college campuses for [many years](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWhejZ7LBOI).  It reached a new level of mainstream appreciation with the introduction of the televised American acapella game-show style competition "[The Sing Off](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMoF3K4UEsg)," and the subsequent popularity of the show's most famous winners, [Pentatonix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_YcIaWirew).  This is the style most people mean currently when they use the term "acapella."

Comment: The link to the "acapella R&B hits" isn't working for me, could you check it please?