# What is the name of music genre that makes music from cups or human body sounds?

Tags: identify-this-genre

What is the name of music genre that makes music from cups or human body sounds?

Like the intro part of this track:

- [Anna Kendrick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Kendrick) - [Cups (Pitch Perfect's "When I'm Gone")](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cmSbXsFE3l8)

Comment: Try to check [this question on Music SE](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/546), maybe you'll find some terminology linked to your question too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [body percussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_percussion).  It's not a genre *per se* but it's often found in modern acapella (see [Genre of song where instruments are replaced by vocals](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/3967/genre-of-song-where-instruments-are-replaced-by-vocals) for more).